# Solving 3rd degree inequality

Tags: inequality, polynomials

I'm working on a CS problem and I'm trying to lower the problems complexity from $O(n)$ to $O(1)$.
After some calculations the problem comes down to solving a 3rd degree Polynomial. The problem I ran into, and the reason I'm asking for help is that I can't factor it to solve for $n$. It looks like this :

$$n(n+1)(2n+1)\le k$$

$n,k$ both positive integers.
$k$ is a constant, it will be known at compile time. I am trying to find the biggest $n$ that satisfies this inequality. I know its a high school problem and it's embarrassing but I spent too much time on it and I need to move on.

Comment: Is $n$ an integer? $k$?

Comment: N and k are both positive integers,added that to edits

Comment: If $k$ is known at build time, who not solve the entire inequality at build time too?

Comment: @Troposphere because that requires a loop. It's by far the easiest solution with O(n) complexity in 2 minutes. I just wanted to go a step further and make it O(1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a formula for the roots of a cubic polynomial. You can see it on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation) and many other places on the internet.

It's ugly, but you can use it in a program to solve your inequality as if it were an inequality, and then round down.

Comment: Are you talking about [this](https://math.vanderbilt.edu/schectex/courses/cubic/) ?
I have found this ,I just hoped that I wouldn't have to go there.

Comment: @YosokuDenkai Yes. It's straightforward to package the ugly algebra in an $O(1)$ function call. You might even find the code on the web somewhere. In python, numpy will find the roots of any polynomial.

Comment: This will do then, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Using algebra, consider first the equation $$x(x+1)(2x+1)= k\implies 2 x^3+3 x^2+x-k=0$$
For sure $\Delta=1-108k^2 <0$ and then only one real root.

Using the hyperbolic method, the solution is
$$x=\frac{\cosh \left(\frac{1}{3} \cosh ^{-1}\left(6 \sqrt{3}
   k\right)\right)}{\sqrt{3}}-\frac{1}{2}$$ Then you need
$$n \leq \left\lfloor \frac{\cosh \left(\frac{1}{3} \cosh ^{-1}\left(6 \sqrt{3}
   k\right)\right)}{\sqrt{3}}-\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor$$
Trying for $k=12345$, this gives $x=17.8482$, then $n=17$. Checking
$$17\times 18\times 35=10710 < 12345 \quad \text{while} \quad 18\times 19\times 37=12654 > 12345$$

Answer (score 0):

The left-hand side is a cubic that goes to $\infty$ as $n$ does. So start with $n = \sqrt[3]{k/2}$ and use a binary search to narrow in on the largest possible $n$. That gets you to $\log_2 n$ at least.